# Syntax problems with restrictions in MICE package in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I recently discovered the MICE package in R for multiple imputation and I am currently learning my way around the package. I want to try to
  set restrictions on some of the variables I impute. While the book "Flexible Imputation of Missing Data" provides some
  simple examples, I want to get the hang of some more complex restrictions. However, I am having some trouble figuring out how to 
  properly specify the restrictions.

For example, consider the following dataset:

```
#Variables to use for restrictions'     
Var1= c(6, 10, 2, 12, 15, NA, 14, NA, 16, 2, 1, 0, 20, NA,NA,NA, 9, 17, 15,13)' 
 Var2= c(35, NA, 23,22, 33, 45, NA, 34, 12, 32, 33, 18, 18,NA,NA, NA, 22, NA, 19, 35)

  #Testvariable 1 check imputation restrictions
  TestVar1 = c(54, 6000, 56,42, 53, 63, 700, 52, 48, 47, 54, 69, 61,935,675, 456, 42, 912, 59, 55)

  #Variable I want to impute given certain restrictions
  MaininterestVar = c(1, NA, 0, 1, 1, NA, NA ,NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 1)

  #Overview of the data
   dat=data.frame(Var1 = Var1, Var2 = Var2, TestVar1 = TestVar1,     MaininterestVar = MaininterestVar)
   View(dat)`
```

I want to set MaininterestVar to specific values given values for Var1 and Varlo2 (regardless of being observed or imputed). I think 
  the most straightforward way to do this would be through post-processing. I can manage simple restrictions such as setting MaininterestVar
  to 1 if Var1 is higher than 8:

```
library(mice)

base_imputation <- mice(dat, m=0, maxit = 0, seed = 835)
post <-base_imputation$post
methods = base_imputation$meth

post["MaininterestVar"] <- "imp[[j]][p$data$Var1[!r[,j]]>8,i]  <- 1"
Restricted_imputation<- mice(dat, m=2, maxit = 20,method = methods,post=post, seed = 835) 

   #looks ok
completeoverview= complete(Restricted_imputation,1)
View(completeoverview)
completeoverview2= complete(Restricted_imputation,2)
View(completeoverview2)
```

However, I run into the following issues:

1) How can I ensure that MaininterestVar is set to 0 for Var1<8? While this seems to go right in this example, this is not a specific restriction and I want to ensure this occurs.

2) Suppose that instead of 0, I want to set MaininterestVar to the value listed in TestVar1 in the same row as the imputed MaininterestVar? 
   For example, the imputed value for MaininterestValue in row 2 would read 6000, depending on whether the observed or imputed value for Var 1 is <8. I think this
   should be doable by specifying the row index of the variable that is being imputed, but I am having trouble correctly specifying it.

The following code:

```
base_imputation <- mice(dat, m=0, maxit = 0, seed = 835)
post <-base_imputation$post
methods = base_imputation$meth

post["MaininterestVar"] <- "imp[[j]][p$data$Var1[!r[,j]]>8,i]  <- p$data$TestVar1[!r[,j]]"
Restricted_imputation<- mice(dat, m=2, maxit = 20,method = methods,post=post, seed = 835)
```

Gives me the error:

```
 iter imp variable
  1   1  Var1  Var2  MaininterestVarError in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`,     p$data$Var1[!r[, j]] > 8, i, value = c(6000,  : 
  replacement has 8 rows, data has 6
```

Which suggests that some additional row index specification is needed, though I'm not quite sure how to do so.

3) Finally, suppose I want to set MaininterestVar to 0 if Var1<5 (this goes against the general data pattern, I'm using this to check if the restriction works) and Var2>28. 
   I have tried specifications such as:

```
base_imputation <- mice(dat, m=0, maxit = 0, seed = 835)
post <-base_imputation$post
methods = base_imputation$meth

post["MaininterestVar"] <- "imp[[j]][(p$data$Var1[!r[,j]]<5)&(p$data$Var2[!r[,j]]>28),i]  <- 1"
Restricted_imputation<- mice(dat, m=2, maxit = 20,method = methods,post=post, seed = 835) 

completeoverview= complete(Restricted_imputation,1)
View(completeoverview)

#Row 2 in completeoverview is 1, despite Var1 being 10.
```

But MICE doesn't seem to handle both restrictions at once (and doesn't provide an error message that it doesn't), or issue 1) happens here.

Thanks in advance!